# A subset of nonzero integers that for every three elements of it, we have: $b_1 \not= b_2 + b_3$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $A $ is a subset of nonzero integers with $n $ elements, is there any subset of A such B with $|B| \geq n/3$ that for every three elements of B, we have: $b_1 \not= b_2 + b_3$?

Edit:

For example if $|A| =$ {1, -1, 2, 4, 6, 9, -5, -8, -7}
then $|B| $ can be {1, 2, 4, -8} because we cannot find any subset of $|B| $ with three elements that in that subset, any two elements sum to a third one.

Now my question is that can we find such $|B|$ for any given $|A|$?

Comment: Your question has 3 upvotes (at the time of this post). However, it may soon be closed unless you provide context.

Comment: Erdös [proved](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c486389h1486622_sumfree_sets_erdos) a stronger version of this in 1965 (he allowed $b_2 = b_3$, so $\{1,2,4,-8\}$ would not count as an answer).  Related: [A Question on a Proof for Erdos' Basic Sumfree Set Theorem (1965)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005018/a-question-on-a-proof-for-erdos-basic-sumfree-set-theorem-1965)