# Subset $B$ of $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}^+$ such that no two elements in $B$ add up to another element in $B$, and $|B|\ge \frac 13 |S|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Given a set $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}+$ with a finite number of elements, show that one can always choose a set $B\subseteq S$ such that for all $x, y, z\in B$ (not necessarily distinct), $x+y\neq z$ and $|B|\ge \frac 13|S|$.

So far, I have found that if $S$ is the set of the first $n$ positive integers, the result is true because one can take all the elements that are $1\pmod 3$, and the sum of two of them will never equal to another element. The sum of two elements will always be $2\pmod 3$, which no element in this subset is. However, I am having trouble generalizing this to all sets.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Probabilistic Method(Alon-Spencer), Theorem 1.4.1

Comment: This is a famous result due to Paul Erdos (1965). The crucial idea is to realize that the subset $\{k+1,\ldots,2k,2k+1\}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, where $p=3k+2$ is prime, is actually sumfree modulo $p$. See, e.g here for more details https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005018/a-question-on-a-proof-for-erdos-basic-sumfree-set-theorem-1965

Comment: But this is also present in the book by Alon and Spencer, as was mentioned above.